# Install Specific Git Branch

Tags: iphone, git, sdk, github, branch

I'm new to git. I want to use this code:

https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON/tree/feature/ARC

But, when I install it using git on my local machine

$ git submodule add git://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON.git

I can only see the master branch

$ git branch
* master

how do I use the feature/ARC branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly like it should be:

```
git clone https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON.git
cd TouchJSON
git checkout feature/ARC
```

Or

```
git clone https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON.gib -b feature/ARC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout feature/ARC
```

Cheers!